# How do i redirect a mailto call from a windows 2008 server to the connected remote desktop client user

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, rdp

I have a windows 2008 server running an ERP system. This system can send mail from within the application by calling the standard mailto action. Our users connect to the server through RDP and I want to use the connected client his mail program, not the local server mail program (which is not installed).

Does anyone have a bright idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would need to be a custom application that uses RDP virtual channels.  This is not trivial, and would require installing the custom-developed component on both the terminal server and remote desktop client.

Virtual Channels is how all RDP redirection functions work, such as audio, clipboard, printing, and drive redirection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383546%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done. I know citrix has some protocol redirection features, but I think these are designed to go the other way - when client clicks a mailto link locally the mailto link is redirected to the terminal server. AFAIK, Windows doesn't have anything like this builtin.